# Why Interceptor not working with capacitor-community/http?

Tags: angular, http, ionic-framework, capacitor

My problem is that my interceptors not working with library `capacitor-community/http`.

I develop my app in Ionic and how can you see I provide interceptor in module. This is really problem with this library because my interceptors working with HttpClient from angular. More you can see in codes and images.

Interceptor:

```
@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(
        private authService: AuthService,
    ) { }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        
    console.log("I am here");
    
    return next.handle(request).pipe( 
            catchError(err => {
                const error = err.message || err.statusText;

                return throwError(error);
            })
        );
    }
}
```

calling method:

```
this.authService.login(item.username, item.password).pipe(
    finalize(() => {
        console.log("end");
    }),
).subscribe();
```

service with @capacitor-community/http:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrXBu.png)

```
login(username: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    const options = {
        url:this.resourceUrl + "/login",
        data: {
            username: username,
            password: password
        },
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    };
    
    return from(Http.post(options));
}
```

service with httpClient from @angular/common/http:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmNgH.png)

```
login(username: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>(this.resourceUrl + "/login", { username, password });
}
```

appModule:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, 
    HttpClientModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: JwtInterceptor, multi: true },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorInterceptor, multi: true },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
```

Comment: Because angular http interceptors are specifically for use with the angular http client…. And will not work with any arbitrary http client… if you want to use some third party http client, you also need to use whatever form of interceptor they provide, if any

Comment: Thanks for the answer and I thought there was this problem and if the library doesn't have an interceptor I have to do it manually in every http call right?

Comment: You could write some service that wraps the http client you wish to use and apply any global request / response processing actions there. Or you could implement your own form of interceptors.

Comment: Hello @AdamBarča how did you solve this issue? i am also facing same issue can you share your solution please Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the way I "hacked" it is: use the navite http only for the login or your very first request which is usually anonymous, after that use the angular http and the interceptor works without any CORS issues. However the best approach would be to have the interceptor specifically built for capaitor http

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was to use this library:
https://github.com/sneas/ionic-native-http-connection-backend#readme